# Bluesnap marketplace - How can I stop a vendor from selling?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, marketplace, bluesnap

I'm working with my marketplace using an app, where vendors basically put in purchases for me and they get their default commission. It's all running smoothly, but I have one vendor that I asked to stop selling, and he still going on. I can't access his phone or disable his app - can I stop him from selling for me on the BlueSnap side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick answer is yes - you can stop him from selling, and you have full control on that on the BlueSnap side.

According to the BlueSnap documentation here: https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-JSON/docs/update-vendor you can set the field **accountStatus** in the vendorAgreement section to "INACTIVE", which will freeze instantly that vendor's ability to sell for you. You can unfreeze them at any time.

If you have similar issues in the future with other vendors and want a less dramatic measure to get them to do as you ask, remember you can also update their default vendor commission to a lower amount, by changing **commissionPercent** in the vendorAgreement.